# What aircraft is shown in this cockpit picture?

Tags: aircraft-identification, cockpit

While watching [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/xbCTTKw3o5o?list=PLiNyr6QSO28P2bKMcv2O_lK83jsR0A9-W&t=1735), I saw a stock image of a cockpit (at 28:55; unrelated to the rest of the video), which I didn't recognise:

[image: Unknown Cockpit]

The general design and some panels look very Airbus like, but it doesn't agree with any Airbus model I'm familiar with. In particular, the screen layout is quite different.

A Google reverse image search brought me to [this Shutterstock image](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/flight-deck-modern-aircraft-pilots-work-1120453592), which shows a wider angle (and also the typical Airbus fire handles), but the description doesn't help:

> Flight Deck of modern aircraft. Pilots at work. Clouds view from the plane cockpit.

**Which aircraft is shown in the image?**

Comment: Yes, youtube creators make extensive use of stock images.  You found the exact image.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I am fairly certain what you're looking at is the cockpit of an [SSJ100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Superjet_100), it has a similar sidestick layout to Airbus, but it was the window opening mechanism that is quite distinctive.

[image]

The layout of controls and screens also very closely matches your original picture, as well as the blank spaces where a clipboard exists in the wikimedia picture, and what looks like a tablet computer exists in yours.

Comment: https://www.airliners.net/photo/Interjet/Sukhoi-SSJ-100-95B-Superjet/2416045/L

Comment: Yep, that's definitely it. I was wondering why it looks so Airbus like. The Wikipedia page says "Key suppliers were selected in October 2003, including Thales for avionics [...]" and Thales is also providing [flight deck avionics equipment](https://www.thalesgroup.com/en/markets/aerospace/flight-deck-avionics-equipment-functions) for Airbus.

Comment: Related Q&A: [Sukhoi Superjet 100 avionics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65419/14897) – @Bianfable