# What aircraft has this cockpit?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What is the aircraft shown in the cockpit photo below?
It was sent to me by someone who claims to be a pilot of this aircraft but I have my suspicions.

[image: Portrait-mode photo of an aircraft flight deck showing the center console with two thrust levers, FMS entry keyboards, trim wheel, etc; "glass cockpit" avionics screens; autopilot controls; etc.]

Comment: May I ask the reason for your suspicions?

Answer (score 5):

It is an **Airbus A320 family** aircraft.

Based on the general layout and design, it looks like an Airbus aircraft (although that can be [misleading](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/93068/33692) sometimes). There are a few distinctive items to look at when distinguishing between different Airbus aircraft:

##### Engine instruments

The earlier A300 and A310 still used analog engine instruments, excluding these types since your picture shows the engine instruments on the upper central screen:

[image: Airbus A310 cockpit]

##### Thrust levers

The Airbus A340 and A380 have 4 engines and therefore 4 thrust levers, excluding these types since your picture shows only 2 thrust levers:

[image: A340 comparison]

##### Screens

The newer A350 uses wider screens, excluding this type since your picture shows much smaller screens:

[image: A350 comparison]

The A380 and the similar looking [SSJ100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Superjet_100) have taller screens instead:

[image: A380 and SSJ100 comparison]

##### Alternate Landing Gear Extension

This leaves us with the A320 and A330, which have very similar cockpit layouts. One easy way to distinguish them is the alternate landing gear extension system (the one for the A320 is mechanical and located on the rear pedestal, the one for the A330 is located just below the gear lever, marked in red below):

[image: A330 comparison]

Also note the different landing gear indicator layout (marked in green in the pictures above), since the A330 accommodates for the extra center landing gear of the A340 (same family).

##### Conclusion

Therefore, the picture you show must be an A320 family aircraft. It is impossible to say which one (A318, A319, A320 or A321) based on that picture. Here is a comparison of the glareshield and pedestal:

[image: A320 comparison]

And here for the overhead panel:

[image: A320 Overhead comparison]

---

Image sources: [A310](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airbus_A310-204,_S7_-_Siberia_Airlines_AN1455269.jpg), [A340](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:A340-642_flight_deck.jpg), [A350](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airbus_A350_demonstration_at_Tehran_Mehrabad_Airport_(7).jpg), [A380](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airbus_A380_cockpit.jpg), [SSJ100](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:15-07-14-Suchoj-Superjet-100-RalfR-WMA_0547-0550.jpg), [A330](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A330_Cockpit.jpg) and [A320](https://www.airbus.com/en/products-services/commercial-aircraft/cockpits).

Comment: Nice. Anything to distinguish this from an A-220 or the SSJ?

Comment: @RalphJ The SSJ can be quite confusing (hence my [recent question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/93068/what-aircraft-is-shown-in-this-cockpit-picture)). To me, the biggest visual difference is the screens (using portrait mode instead of square or landscape). The A220 looks [a lot more different](https://ccntservice.airbus.com/apps/cockpits/a220/index.php) since it was designed by Bombardier (C series).

Answer (score 4):

It matches very closely to this picture of an Airbus A320 cockpit.

[image]

Taken from Wikipedia at:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airbus_A320-214_Vueling_EC-HHA_cockpit_(5508849819).jpg