# Is the cockpit depicted in this movie from an Airbus A330?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I am watching [this YouTube movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KK5KTQGuXSQ&t=19s):

And I wonder, if it is possible to tell the aircraft being flown here, just from looking at the cockpit instruments (quite low quality) or other information that can be found in this movie?

Searching the Internet for part of the title (`Miami Approach - TCAS Alert Licence to Fly`) has brought me to [this book at Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/CPT-Thomas-Frick-Hd-Operations/dp/B01KU3AE9S/ref=sr_1_1?camp=1638&creative=6742&keywords=pilotseye+miami&linkCode=ur2&qid=1676284115&sr=8-1):

[image]

Based on the above, can we confirm that the depicted aircraft is in fact an Airbus A330?

Comment: I'm not sure I would agree with calling it a movie, nor the last link a book.

Comment: @CGCampbell Hm... "clip" and "printed guide"?

Comment: @trejder The Amazon link for is a Blu-Ray disc containing the whole documentary film from which the YouTube clip was taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, that is an Airbus A330.**

Consider the following scene from the video ([0:13](https://youtu.be/KK5KTQGuXSQ?t=13)):

[image: A330 cockpit from video]

The area circled in red is the landing gear indicator and the area in green is the alternate landing gear extension. This layout and design is very characteristic for the A330 (and similar to the A340, but with a center body gear, see e.g. [this image](https://www.airteamimages.com/airbus-a340__-_47907_large.html); you can also clearly see only two thrust levers, further excluding the A340). For reference, compare to this picture of an A330 cockpit from Wikipedia:

[image: A330 cockpit reference picture]
<sup>(cropped from [Wikipedia A330 Cockpit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:A330_Cockpit.jpg))</sup>

*Note:* this picture shows an older aircraft with analog standby instruments (to the left of the two central screens). The aircraft in the video already has the modern digital standby instrument.

For more details on how to distinguish different Airbus cockpits, see [What aircraft has this cockpit?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/93117/33692)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Combined with the wing views and the callsign (LX64) it is clear that this is a Swiss A330.